# How to Jump from Master ASPX page to a specific section (div) on a Child aspx page

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, navigateurl

1. I have a master aspx page and it has menu controls and need to navigate it to child aspx page and jump/scroll to specific div section.
2. I have used Response.redriect("http://url/landing.aspx/#divSection") but it does not exactly navigates. The landing page contain the video embedded.
3. if it is in the same page, then javascript can be registered and called.
4. Can any one suggest how to achieve this.

Comment: Try http://url/landing.aspx#divSection"? Either way I think you need to include the relevant code snippets in your question.

Comment: There is no reason this should not work, unless some code is jumping to the top of the page or you are missing `divSection` somewhere.